# Autoscroll in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using version 12 community edition. Is there a way to enable *"autoscroll"* feature in settings or add it through some plugin?

Picture of "autosroll" (not really sure if I'm calling it right) addon from VS:

[image]

Comment: what does it actually do? There's the "Autoscroll from/to Source" feature but it doesn't seem to be the same according to your description. Or?

Comment: nope. what I mean is the same behaviour like firefox/IE/chrome has after clicking a page with middle mouse button (under windows).

found a better description of it - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/what-should-the-middle-mouse-button-mean.html - section "Another odd middle-click behavior"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA, and I'm not aware of any plugin that does that.